# Sql query to find and count the references in another table

Tags: sql

I have two tables in SQL as shown below

collection table:

```
+--------------+-------------------------+----------------+---------------+----------+
| CollectionID | Name                    | Useful data    | Useful data 2 | CollID   |
+--------------+-------------------------+----------------+---------------+----------+
| GCP00034     | Amsterdam [Managed]     | 1/15/21 8:17   | 6/14/23 9:23  | 16777261 |
+--------------+-------------------------+----------------+---------------+----------+
| GCP00036     | Buenos Aires [Managed]  | 7/30/19 10:01  | 6/14/23 9:25  | 16777263 |
+--------------+-------------------------+----------------+---------------+----------+
| GCP00037     | Branford [Managed]      | 7/30/19 9:58   | 6/14/23 9:24  | 16777264 |
+--------------+-------------------------+----------------+---------------+----------+
| GCP00038     | Washington DC [Managed] | 7/30/19 10:10  | 6/14/23 9:29  | 16777265 |
+--------------+-------------------------+----------------+---------------+----------+
| GCP00039     | Edmonton [Managed]      | 11/25/21 18:20 | 6/14/23 9:25  | 16777266 |
+--------------+-------------------------+----------------+---------------+----------+
| GCP00D58     | sample 1                | 1/15/21 8:17   | 6/14/23 9:23  | 16777261 |
+--------------+-------------------------+----------------+---------------+----------+
```

Query rule table

```
+--------------+--------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+--+
| CollectionID | RuleName                             | QueryID | QueryExpression |  |
+--------------+--------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+--+
| GCP016CA     | Mapped to User Collection            | 1       |                 |  |
+--------------+--------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+--+
| GCP016CB     | WQL query                            | 1       |                 |  |
+--------------+--------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+--+
| GCP016D5     | Mapped to user collection - GCP01085 | 1       |                 |  |
+--------------+--------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+--+
| GCP016EA     | Mapped to user collection            | 1       |                 |  |
+--------------+--------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+--+
| GCP017A9     | User to Devices                      | 1       |                 |  |
+--------------+--------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+--+
| GCP017E2     | Mapped to user colleciton - GCP000AD | 1       |                 |  |
+--------------+--------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+--+
| GCP017F6     | Noncompliant                         | 1       |                 |  |
+--------------+--------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+--+
```

and Query expression column can have value like below.

## Sample :1

```
SELECT ALL
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.ItemKey,
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.DiscArchKey,
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name0,
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMS_Unique_Identifier0,
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.Resource_Domain_OR_Workgr0,
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client0
FROM
    vSMS_R_System AS SMS_R_System
WHERE
    SMS_R_System.ItemKey IN (SELECT ALL
            SMS_UserMachineRelationship.MachineResourceID
        FROM
            _RES_COLL_GCP00D58 AS SMS_CM_RES_COLL_GCP00D58
                INNER JOIN
            v_UserMachineRelationship AS SMS_UserMachineRelationship ON SMS_UserMachineRelationship.UniqueUserName = SMS_CM_RES_COLL_GCP00D58.SMSID)
```

## Sample :2

```
SELECT ALL
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.ItemKey,
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.DiscArchKey,
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name0,
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMS_Unique_Identifier0,
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.Resource_Domain_OR_Workgr0,
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client0
FROM
    vSMS_R_System AS SMS_R_System
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    v_UserMachineRelationship AS SMS_UserMachineRelationship ON SMS_UserMachineRelationship.MachineResourceID = SMS_R_System.ItemKey
WHERE
    SMS_UserMachineRelationship.UniqueUserName IN (SELECT ALL
            SMS_R_User.Unique_User_Name0
        FROM
            User_DISC AS SMS_R_User
                INNER JOIN
            _RES_COLL_GCP000DC AS SMS_CM_RES_COLL_GCP000DC ON SMS_CM_RES_COLL_GCP000DC.MachineID = SMS_R_User.ItemKey)
```

## Sample :3

```
SELECT ALL
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.ItemKey,
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.DiscArchKey,
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name0,
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMS_Unique_Identifier0,
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.Resource_Domain_OR_Workgr0,
    SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client0
FROM
    vSMS_R_System AS SMS_R_System
        INNER JOIN
    vdcmdeploymentsystemdetails AS ___System_DCMDeploymentState0 ON ___System_DCMDeploymentState0.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ItemKey
WHERE
    ((___System_DCMDeploymentState0.BaselineID = N'SCOPEID_06B16002-AAF3-48AB-AB20-21E5C5471EAE/BASELINE_B30E0775-C6EF-4095-84C7-CC7BB5DBB0
        AND ___System_DCMDeploymentState0.CollectionID = N'GCP00764')
        AND ___System_DCMDeploymentState0.ComplianceState = 3)
```

What I am trying to achieve is to add a reference count in the `collection table` record when a `collection code (GCP*****)` is identified in a `query expression`. If a `sample:1` value is present twice in the `query rule` table, then in the `collection` table, it should look like the following example:

```
+--------------+----------+--------------+---------------+----------+-----------------+
| CollectionID | Name     | Useful data  | Useful data 2 | CollID   | reference count |
+--------------+----------+--------------+---------------+----------+-----------------+
| GCP00D58     | sample 1 | 1/15/21 8:17 | 6/14/23 9:23  | 16777261 | 2               |
+--------------+----------+--------------+---------------+----------+-----------------+
```

I have not done string match operation before and looking forward to get guidance from experts here.

Comment: The column QueryExpression contains complete SQL query strings? And you want to count occurences of `'GCP...'` in these strings? So, zero for sample 1, zero for sample2, one for sample 3?  What DBMS are you using? Always tag your SQL requests qith your DBMS in order to get answers that work for you.

Comment: thanks for reading thorugh my post! the query expression is WQL and it follows SQL structure. Both these "Query table" and "collection Table" are in MS SQL .
 Sample 1 contains  the string "GCP00D58"  3 times
Sample 2 contains the string  "GCP000DC" 3 times
sample 3 contains the string "GCP00764" only once.
But my ask is if "sample 1" is in the first two records of "Query rule" table then it should be counted as 2.
Again Thank you so much for your time and help

Comment: From a simplistic point-of-view, you'll likely just be looking to use a LIKE operator (eg. QueryExpression LIKE ('%' + CollectionId + '%') - but one big initial assumption that's going to go along with that is that your CollectionId values are ALWAYS 8 characters in length .... otherwise, if you've got a CollectionId value that is just GCP0076 and also CollectionId values GCP00761, GCP00762, ...763, ...764, etc. - then using LIKE is unlikely (no pun intended) to meet your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to get my desired count from the below query

```
select 
Substring(QueryExpression, PATINDEX('%GCP%', QueryExpression), 8) as 'RefrencedID',
count(CollectionID) as 'Count'
From Queryrule 
where 
QueryExpression like '%gcp[0-9ABCDEF][0-9ABCDEF][0-9ABCDEF][0-9ABCDEF][0-9ABCDEF]%'
group by Substring(QueryExpression, PATINDEX('%GCP%', QueryExpression), 8)
```

Then i joined the `refrencedID` to `CollectionID` on the `Collection table`. Feel free to correct me if this can be a better way. Thanks alot everyone for your time and suggestions on this.